# Exim Server on port 465 does not send banner nor respond to EHLO command

Tags: smtp, centos7, exim

I have developed an application that sends emails using my Exim server over a SSL connection.

According to my default exim configuration, to send e-mails over SSL connection I need to use port 465, while to send e-mails with no SSL, I have to use port 587.

Well, when I configure the e-mail sender to use SSL and I use port 587, it fails sending, but if I use port 465, it sends the e-mail correctly, which is the expected behaviour.

However, if I telnet to the server using port 587, server returns the SMTP banner and if I issue an EHLO command, this is returned:

```
250-vps.desytec.com Hello  [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]                                                                             
250-SIZE 52428800                                                                                                       
250-8BITMIME                                                                                                            
250-PIPELINING                                                                                                          
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN                                                                                                    
250-STARTTLS                                                                                                            
250 HELP
```

Notice that on port 587, TLS connection is supported.

But if I telnet the server to port 465, no banner neither EHLO response are shown.

How can I make my Exim server, on port 465, to send the banner, command echoes and command responses?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: What program is listening on port 465?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is Exim server

Comment: 587 supports STARTTLS which is an upgrade to TLS from an initial cleartext connection. 465 is SMTP in wrapper mode, ie. over a pure TLS connection (from the moment the connection is established).

Comment: You do not want to make port 465 server work in a non-standard way. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen nothing special..... it seems Mail classes in .NET Framework have some sort of problems. I changed to use MailKit and problem is gone. It allowed me to use 465 port with SSL connection.

Answer (score 3):

465 is smtps port, it's waiting for ssl connection. Use `stunnel` or `openssl` or `socat` for connecting to it.